# Form Request Validation returns empty error messages – Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I've got a problem with error messages during validation in Laravel. I've got my custom Request:

```
class CreateCv extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Fill the name!',
            'surname.required'  => 'Fill the surname!',
        ];
    }
}
```

and then I've got a controller with create method:

```
class CvController extends Controller
{

    public function create(Requests\CreateCv $request) {
        return response()->json(['ok' => true], 200);
    }
}
```

If everything is filled up, then it returns json response `"ok" : true` correctly. But when something is missing, then it returns empty msg: `"msg": ""`. What causes this problem?

**EDIT**
here's the handler.php file

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontReport = [
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        //ValidationException::class,
    ];

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        parent::report($e);
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        return $e;
        //return response()->json(['msg' => $e->getMessage()], 422);
        //return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Can you try in your CreateCv class to extend Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest.
- I encountered this recently during creating an API for a web application, every time I test the validation fields without the Accept application/json header, the errors object (I customized the ValidationException to return an errors object) is always empty.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work ... `Request` is an abstract class, which extends `FormRequest`

Comment: Are you using postman to test? try to add in your Headers Accept: application/json

Comment: I've tried to add Accept: application/json header in postman, but also without success :(

Comment: Which development environment are you using and which server?

Comment: Look at my edited question, now I'm getting weird exception ... I've got `ValidationException::class` insinde `$dontReport` array before (in Handler)...so it's reason why it was empty ... but now I'm stuck on this

Comment: Can you post your Handler.php file?

Comment: It's in question now :)

Comment: if you uncomment the default `return parent::render($request, $e);` and put the Accept: application/json header, then it should return you the an object with the error messages.

Comment: yes, now it works ... I don't remember now, why I made this change :D